# Using client node with the hadoop cluster to run the client jobs

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

i have created a hdfs cluster and also set up a client node .

when a job is submitted to the resource manager it creates a application master which will create a container on the available resources to run the job .

i have to figure out a way to use the client node for creating a container to run the jobs .

how the client node can be used to run the jobs after the available nodes in the cluster are fully utilized .

Comment: YARN cannot create containers after its fully utilized. They will stay in pending state. But, they aren't submitted any differently, so I don't understand the question

Comment: And, as answered before, YARN Containers aren't compatible with the Mesos containerizer formats (unless you enable both to run Docker containers), but at that point, you might as well use Kubernetes or Nomad (where there are alternative storage solutions, better than HDFS)